# Given, $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}+f_1(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=f_2(x)\;\forall x\gt0$. Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, contest-math

The following question is taken from the book 'Advanced Problems in JEE Advanced' by Vikas Gupta.

> Let $f,g,f_1,f_2:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be twice differentiable function, and $f(x)\ge0, f'(x)\ge0, g'(x)\gt0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Also, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f_1(x)=5, \lim_{x\to\infty}f_2(x)=12, \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty, \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$ and $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}+f_1(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=f_2(x)\;\forall x\gt0$. Also, $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are continuous. Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$

I think the problem is saying $f,g$ are unbounded but $f_1,g_1$ are bounded.

Also, from the given equation, $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=f_2(x)-f_1(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$,

At infinity, the behaviour of LHS can be understood as $12-5\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Don't know how to operate after this.

Options given are $0,1,\frac12,2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L:=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. By L'H rule, we get $L=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Thus from the relation taking $x\to \infty$, we get $L+5L=12$, i.e., $L=2$. Hence your answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a more in-depth explanation here.
LH rule is that the  lim→∞f()/g() =  lim→∞f()/g()
so that equates both limits. Thus making the equation L
+5L = 12 (from the previous answer)

Comment: Because of LH,  $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. Take both fractions as L and plug in the given equation.